# How to exit Narrator on Windows Phone?

Tags: 8.1, settings, accessibility, narrator

I nearly hard reset my phone today.

The problem is that while the screen reader works well, it appears almost impossible to scroll the screen, meaning if you exit the settings page it is very difficult to get back to the Accessibility settings item on the Settings page.

How do I turn off the Narrator?

Comment: Go to settings: look for Ease of access and press off the Narrator and Narrator quick launch

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From the same Settings page where you can enable Narrator:

> To turn Narrator off, press and hold the Volume Up button, then press the Start button.

For more information, see [Using Narrator on your phone](http://www.windowsphone.com/en-gb/how-to/wp8/settings-and-personalization/use-narrator-on-my-phone).

Comment: Is it the same for Windows Phone 8.0 ?

Comment: From the link in my answer, it would seem that Narrator is only available in 8.1. Hence why I removed the 8.0 tag from the question. I don't have an 8.0 phone available to check for myself, though.

Comment: From my 8.0 device, I can confirm there is no narrator.

Answer (score 1):

Best method is hold power up key and then double tap on windows key

Answer (score -1):

Hiding the volume up key does not work you have to go turn the narrator off so what you do is keep swiping over with your finger and it will scroll all the way down and take you to setting go to ease of access and turn that *[censured]* off